# Are variadic functions deprecated?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Are variadic-functions kind of deprecated since C++11 has variadic template functions ?
More specifically, do variadic-function have any advantage in a particular situation ?
I know variadic-macros can have their uses. What about variadic functions ?

Comment: Whether they have no use and whether they are deprecated are two unrelated things. Which is it you're asking about?

Comment: No they are not deprecated. Variadic functions is a C feature and in my humble opinion cannot be deprecated due to C++ compatibility with C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Variadic templates are variadic at compile time; variadic functions are variadic at run time. In other words, a variadic template function is compiled to accept however many parameters are passed to it, while a regular variadic function is compiled to accept any number of parameters.

You can put a variadic function like `printf` into a library and ship it to somebody to use without source code. You cannot do that with a template function because its source code needs to be available to the caller.